# How do I get the MapView control to fill the view

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

Changing Mode:  Scale to fit has no effect on the MapView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use the delegate MKMapViewDelegate

Comment: I am talking about in Interface Builder